# Cannot use plot() function in RStudio for large objects

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I am trying to use the default `plot()` function in R to try and plot a shapefile that is about 100MB, using RStudio. When I try and plot the shapefile, the command doesn't finish executing for around 5 minutes, and when it finally does, the plotting window remains blank. When I execute the same process exactly in VS Code, the plot appears almost instantly, as expected.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling RStudio with no success.

Comment: Sounds like a memory limit issue. You could try saving it to disk. `dev.copy(png,'path/pngFile.png');  plot(...);  dev.off()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for what VStudio does, but I can guarantee that plotting 100MB worth of data points is useless (unless the final plot is going to be maybe 6 by 10 meters in size).
First thing: can you load the source file into R at all? One would hope so since that's not a grossly huge data blob.  Then use your choice of reduction algorithms to get a reasonable number of points to plot, e.g.  800 by 1600, which is all a monitor can display anyway.
Next try plotting a small subset to verify the data are in a valid form, etc.
Then consider reducing the data by collapsing maybe each 10x10 region to a single average value,  or by using `ggplot2:geom_hex` .